# How to read and print PropertiesServices from client-side HTML with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, properties

The `foo` variable is sent from the client side `HTML` to `Code.js` as demonstrated by the logs.  When this occurs, the `bar` key from `PropertiesService` is set and logged.

**How is `PropertiesServices` accessed from the client side `HTML` and [output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27628047/20193655) as text?**

logs:

```
Cloud logs
Oct 15, 2022, 5:27:14 PM
Info
logProperties..
Oct 15, 2022, 5:27:14 PM
Info
bar
Oct 15, 2022, 5:27:14 PM
Info
foo
Oct 15, 2022, 5:27:14 PM
Info
sending foo
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function sendFoo()
    {
      var foo = document.getElementById("foo").value;
      google.script.run.setBar(foo);
      document.getElementById("foo").value = '';
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    foo is:<input type="text" id="foo" />
    <input type="button" value="sendFoo" onclick="sendFoo()" /> <br> <br> <br>
    bar is:
  </body>
</html>
```

I believe this can be accomplished with `span` tag.

code:

```
function setBar(foo) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("foo",foo);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("bar","foo received");
  logProperties();
}

function initProperties() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
}

function logProperties() {
  Logger.log("logProperties..");
  var keys = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys();
  keys.forEach(key => {
    Logger.log(key);
    Logger.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key));
  });
}

function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}

function doGet(e) {
  initProperties();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('WebApp');
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}
```

*This is just within `Google Apps Script` and has been kept as simple as possible, but no simpler.*

see also:

https://codewithcurt.com/how-to-call-google-apps-script-function-from-web-app/

Comment: PropertiesService only runs on the server.  It's not part of clientside Javascript.

Comment: There's no such functionality with GAS?  I thought it had that baked in.

Comment: Google Apps Script runs on google servers not on your browser.  Javascript runs on your browswer.  Although some Javascript functions also can run on google servers.

Answer (score 0):

Less than perfect, but [accomplishes](https://codewithcurt.com/how-to-call-google-apps-script-function-from-web-app/) the main goal of getting data from server and displaying client side when requested by the client.

code:

```
var sheetId = "1L3Sd-J780mQtb7JYsmJzInI1kMdrQA8GbLspQJ5eVW4";
var sheetName = "data";

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebApp');
}

function getOneCellData() { 
  Logger.log("getOneCellData..");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue(); 
  return data;  
}

function getMultiCellData() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName); 
  var data = sheet.getRange('A1:C1').getValues(); 
  return data;  
}

function getInOutData(inData) { 
  Logger.log("getInOutData");
  var outData = "IN DATA: " + inData; 
  return outData;  
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script>
  function callOneCellData()
  {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(returnData) 
    {
       document.getElementById("oneCellData").innerHTML = returnData;
    }).getOneCellData();
  }
  
  function callMultiCellData()
  {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(returnArray) 
    {
        console.log(returnArray);
        var stringArray = returnArray.toString();
        document.getElementById("multiData").innerHTML = stringArray;
    }).getMultiCellData();
  }
  
  function callInOutData()
  {
    var inData = document.getElementById("inData").value
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(outData) 
    {
        document.getElementById("outData").innerHTML = outData;
    }).getInOutData(inData);
  }
  
  function callData()
  {
    callOneCellData();
    callMultiCellData();
    callInOutData();
  }  
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <label>One Cell Data</label><br><textarea id="oneCellData" ></textarea><br>
  <label>Multi Data</label><br><textarea id="multiData" ></textarea><br>
  <label>In Data</label><br><input type="text" id="inData" /><br>
  <label>Out Data</label><br><textarea id="outData" ></textarea><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="callData()" value="Get Data" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I had thought this was best done with `Properties` but that may not be so.

*Ideally*, would display the above `textarea` as just "plain" text.