# HTML Service instead of UI service ( which is deprecated) to create dashboard based on data stored in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone please show me an example on how to use HTML Service instead of UI service ( which is deprecated) to create dashboard based on data stored in Google Spreadsheet?

Cheers 
Chok

Comment: You can refer to these links:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices   http://ctrlq.org/code/19348-htmlservice-google-apps-script

Comment: Thanks for sharing then link @KRR.

As per my understanding the basic code of the script file will be something like this 

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('0AvdEplRHp5dGc4Wc')
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}

But I am not sure of code syntax in HTML file to draw the bar chart based on the Google Sheet file.

Please suggest

Comment: You can look at other posts, like this one: [Stack Overflow - Form in Google Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623676/edit-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet-via-a-form-of-sorts-or-alert-box-using-data/27626884#27626884)

Comment: Please update your question with the information that you put in the comment.

Comment: @SandyGood Thank for sharing the link. I am sorry but could't locate the lines of code in HTML formar for bar chart rendering. Please suggest the lines I should refer in the link shared .

Apologies for asking basic questions due to my very limited understanding

Comment: What do you want to trigger the code?  The spreadsheet opening?  A user clicking a menu item?  A user using a pop-up dialog box?

Comment: @SandyGood I have written code which sends email every morning with the link of the dashboard which contains pie chart. The source data of the dashboard is google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

In a spreadsheet you can cause a Modal Dialog box to pop up, which can include custom HTML.

Create an `onOpen()` function in an Apps Script attached to your spreadsheet

- Click the TOOLS menu.
- Click SCRIPT EDITOR.

### Add this Code:

```
// This will run when the spreadsheet is opened or the browser page is refreshed
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Open Dialog Box', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
```

That `onOpen()` function will run when the spreadsheet opens.

Create a function that will run when the menu item is chosen

In a **.gs** script file, add this function.

```
function openDialog() {
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Put a Title Description HERE');
}
```

### Create an index.html file

In the Apps Script code editor,

- Choose FILE, NEW, HTML FILE

### Enter this HTML:

```
<br>

The NEW Zip: <input type="text" />

<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Get The Information" onclick='injectSomeText()'/>
<br>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Get Sheet Data" onclick='getSheetData()'/>

Here is your information!

<div id='myZipInfo'></div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Close"
  onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

<script>
window.injectSomeText = function() {
  console.log('it ran');
  document.getElementById('myZipInfo').textContent = 'This is test text.  It worked!';
};

window.onSuccess = function(returnedData) {
    document.getElementById('myZipInfo').textContent = returnedData;
}

window.getSheetData = function() {

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .readSheetData();
}
</script>
```

Save the file with a name of "index"

### Now add some more code to the Code.gs file.

Code.gs

```
function readSheetData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Column One: ' + data[i][0]);
    Logger.log('Column Two: ' + data[i][1]);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Save the Code.gs file and Refresh the browser window with the Google spreadsheet, and the `onOpen()` function will run.

This example shows the basics of putting HTML, a button and an input field in a Modal Dialog.

You could create a button named to run custom function.

```
<input type="button" value="Run My Function" onclick="google.script.run.fncMyFunction()"/>
```

This example shows that HTML can be injected into the Dialog Box. Click the "Get the Information" button, and text will appear in the Dialog Box.

Note that there is an HTML SCRIPT tag in the HTML of the index.html file. You can actually add client side JavaScript and have it run in a Modal Dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for sharing step by step information @SandyGood . 

One query : Do we need to type all the HTML tags or is there any tool available which can auto generate the HTML tags based on UI design we make.

Comment: I'm sure there is software that will auto generate HTML, but I've never used any.